# WinForms modal windows alt+tab problem

Tags: winforms, modal-dialog, switching

Suppose multiple **Modal Windows** shown above each other. 
All of those have `ShowInTaskbar = false`, which means that in the `TaskBar` you only see the `MainForm` and all Modal Windows are hidden.

Now you press **ALT+ TAB** and the most upper modal Windows disappears. But you cannot get it back in front.

How should be this done correctly in your opinion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a modal window is getting stuck behind the main form, it sounds like you are not setting its owner. When you call `showDialog()`, you need to pass in the main form like this:

```
modalWin.showDialog(mainForm);
```

Any time you call `showDialog()`, and your program has another form that should be underneath, it is best to pass it as the owner. If you show modal window when there is already a modal window up, then pass the first modal window as the owner.

Answer (score 0):

OK Just to complete it:

This is how to set an Owner to be a Winform for a Winform:

```
form.ShowDialog(ownerInstance);
```

This is how to set an Owner to be a Winform for a WPF Window:

```
MyWpfDialog dialog = new MyWpfDialog();
new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(dialog).Owner = ownerInstance.Handle;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

This is how to set an Ownder to be a Wpf Window for a Wpf Window:

```
.Owner = Window.GetWindow(ownerInstance)
```